# Restore disk in single user mode

Tags: command-line, disk-utility

I wonder if it is possible to restore one partition to another in command line? The similar operation can be performed with Disk Utility, but unfortunately I cannot boot in graphics mode (even safe mode does not work). Man page of diskutil does not describe such option. I use Mac OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you can't. If you boot into single-user mode you'll find that diskutil can't run because it's required modules aren't available.

You can try this: http://sabiancrash.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-run-diskutil-in-single-user-mode.html

But, the easiest way would be to use an OSX install CD. Boot from the CD (put it in, hold C at boot). When the installer first loads you can choose Disk Utility from the Tools menu.

Comment: Thanks a million! I totally forgot about installation CD. Anyway it seems diskutil is not able restore the the partition.

Answer (score 0):

Even in single-user mode, diskutil can start and repair permissions.
You'll have to start the following five services first:

1. notifyd
2. configd
3. diskmanagementd
4. securityd
5. disarbitrationd

Details and example-script here: http://www.system-fabrik.de/diskutil-single-user-mode/

Comment: Well, the link with details and example is in German, I do not read it. I'm not interested in repairing the permissions, could you please explicitly mention which command restores one partition to another?

Comment: That link just gave me a black screen. Seems the same instructions are here in English. http://sabiancrash.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-run-diskutil-in-single-user-mode.html